# How to send JSON file to browser using <script> tag like css and js files in MVC.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have JSON file in my application and I am tying to access the data in it using Java script.

**NOTE:** I am not looking for loading JSON file using Ajax call.

**Json file Name:** PhotoDatabase.json

**Json content:**

```
var photosdatabase =
{
  "photos":
  [
    {
      "photo_id": 27932,
      "photo_title": "Atardecer en Embalse",
      "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/27932",
      "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/27932.jpg",
      "longitude": -64.404945,
      "latitude": -32.202924,
    },....
  ]
}
```

HTML call of JSON file:

```
<script type="application/json" src="~/PhotosDatabase.json"></script>
```

Java Script access to json file:

```
pics = photosdatabase.photos;
```

The same works in local Java script files but not working in MVC.

In browser sources the JSON file is not loaded.

Should I add some permissions to make the JSON file load into browser?

Comment: Try making it a `.js` file instead, and accessing the `photosdatabase` property on `window`. (And even though you're not looking to, AJAX would be a good solution. Either way, you're making a request to the server.)

Comment: Well...I tried to use this from few other posts <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent> added it in <system.webserver>.  Didn't work

Comment: @krillgar it works when I change extension to .js I think it works because it has "var photodatabase= ".